# Large sample size and small subpopulation of interest - what is the impact on p-value

Tags: p-value, regression-coefficients, sample-size

Let's say I want to compare the life satisfaction of horse owners (approximately 5% of the sample) to dog owners, and I have n=10,000. In another context, I would say I have a very large sample size, which would probably impact my p-values, but because the subpopulation of interest is so small (only 500 subjects).
I wonder whether this approach with such an unbalanced sample impacts my results and p-values and if so how and why is that?
It is so hard to wrap my head around this.
I've read that with high sample size I should only consider p<0.001 as a statistically significant result if the effect size is not big.
So far my results show that stdy stand estimate=0.60 and p=0.017. (x=binary & y=0-5 life satisfaction scale)

Comment: You can compare group means even with (very) unequal sample sizes (but I'd focus on the effect size of the difference, not the p-value being lower than some threshold or not). However very unequal sample sizes often lead to unequal variances (in which case you shouldn't use ANOVA or regular t-test), so you should check the equality of life satisfaction variance between the groups.

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! However, I have a follow-up question: what test would you recommend for testing the equality between unbalanced groups?

Comment: For equality of variances, you can use for instance F-test or Levene's test.